# Ignore directory without permission (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) in recursive file search

Tags: c#, directory

My program should search all drives and folders for files with a specific file name. At the beginning of my search it throws a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` at this line in my code.

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
```

This is the code I am using. How could I fix it so that it ignores directories with this problem and continues the search.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        searchDirectory(d.ToString(), true);
    }
}

public static void searchDirectory(string drive, bool doSubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(drive);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if (file.Name.Contains("something"))
        {
             do something.... xD
        }
    }

    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            //string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            searchDirectory(subdir.FullName, doSubdirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply wrapping the code in a try catch?

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(drive);
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (file.Name.Contains("something"))
                {
                    //do something.... xD
                }
            }

            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    //string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    searchDirectory(subdir.FullName, doSubdirs);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        { }
```